# Camera not capturing the base plane in rendering

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am a newbie to blender

Created a low poly ice field like so

Blender version 2.8

[image]

When I render the scene, the camera is skipping the base plane & just showing the remaining objects like so.

[image]

I've spent quite some time on this, trying to figure why this is happening but no luck. Need help guys

I've tried copying everything into a new file that doesn't work. The issue persists. I've restarted blender multiple times that doesn't help.

I've got two particle settings in the project. Updated below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the file?

Comment: @Crantisz how do I post the file, can I attach it here?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an image of the settings for the particles. It looks like the emitter is disabled for rendering.

Comment: @cegaton updated

Comment: It doesn't help if you don't show the whole thing. In the Render section of the particles settings, is the emitter enabled?

Comment: @cegaton yeap, the emitter was off. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the particle settings make sure that the particles are enabled for Rendering

[image]